# Data cleansing and formatting script

Tags: python, excel, sqlite, pandas

This is a script that creates a base dataframe from a sqlite database, adds data to it (also from SQLite), cleanse it and formats it all to an Excel file.  I feel like it is incredibly verbose and my code could be simplified quite a bit.  One thing I **definitely** want to do is eliminate the direct references to the db, `/Users/meter/code/mm/vid_score/test.db` so that this script can be run on any machine.

Any thoughts on simple changes I can make to decrease the complexity and amount of code?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlite3 as db
from contextlib import closing
from datetime import date, timedelta

ONE = date.today() - timedelta(1)
TWO = date.today() - timedelta(2)
SEVEN = date.today() - timedelta(8)


def video_base():
    with closing(db.connect('/Users/meter/code/mm/vid_score/test.db')) as con:
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM video_played;", con)

    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.date

    df = df.drop('index', axis=1)

    df_one = df.loc[df['time'] == ONE]
    df_two = df.loc[df['time'] == TWO]
    df_seven = df.loc[df['time'] == SEVEN]

    df_one = df_one.groupby('video_id').agg({"ios_id": {"count_watched": np.count_nonzero,
                                                        "unique_watched": pd.Series.nunique},
                                             "feed_position": {"feed_position": np.average},
                                             "time_watched": {"time_watched": np.sum},
                                             "video_length": {"video_length": np.sum}})

    df_one.columns = df_one.columns.droplevel(0)
    df_one['avg_time_watched'] = df_one['time_watched'] / df_one['video_length']

    df_two = df_two.groupby('video_id').agg({"ios_id": {"count_watched": np.count_nonzero,
                                                        "unique_watched": pd.Series.nunique},
                                             "feed_position": {"feed_position": np.average},
                                             "time_watched": {"time_watched": np.sum},
                                             "video_length": {"video_length": np.sum}})
    df_two.columns = df_two.columns.droplevel(0)
    df_two = df_two.rename(columns={'count_watched': 'count_watched_yeterday'})

    df_seven = df_seven.groupby('video_id').agg({"ios_id": {"count_watched": np.count_nonzero,
                                                            "unique_watched": pd.Series.nunique},
                                                 "feed_position": {"feed_position": np.average},
                                                 "time_watched": {"time_watched": np.sum},
                                                 "video_length": {"video_length": np.sum}})
    df_seven.columns = df_seven.columns.droplevel(0)
    df_seven = df_seven.rename(columns={'count_watched': 'count_watched_seven'})

    video_base = pd.merge(df_one, df_two[['count_watched_yeterday']],
                          how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)
    video_base = pd.merge(video_base, df_seven[['count_watched_seven']],
                          how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True)

    return video_base


def video_intent(video_base):
    # ITEM INFO #
    with closing(db.connect('/Users/meter/code/mm/vid_score/test.db')) as con:
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM item_info_click;", con)

    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.date
    df = df.drop('index', axis=1)
    df = df.loc[df['time'] == ONE]

    df = df.groupby('video_id').agg({"ios_id": {"count_clicks": np.count_nonzero,
                                                "unique_clicks": pd.Series.nunique},
                                     "feed_position": {"feed_position": np.average}})
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)

    video_base['item_info_clicks'] = df['count_clicks']

    # FAVED #
    with closing(db.connect('/Users/meter/code/mm/vid_score/test.db')) as con:
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM faved;", con)

    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.date
    df = df.drop('index', axis=1)
    df = df.loc[df['time'] == ONE]

    df = df.groupby('video_id').agg({"ios_id": {"count_faves": np.count_nonzero,
                                                "unique_clicks": pd.Series.nunique},
                                     "feed_position": {"feed_position": np.average}})
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)

    video_base['faves'] = df['count_faves']

    # REPLAYS #
    with closing(db.connect('/Users/meter/code/mm/vid_score/test.db')) as con:
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM replay;", con)

    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.date
    df = df.drop('index', axis=1)
    df = df.loc[df['time'] == ONE]

    df = df.groupby('video_id').agg({"ios_id": {"replays": np.count_nonzero,
                                                "unique_clicks": pd.Series.nunique},
                                     "feed_position": {"feed_position": np.average}})
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)

    video_base['replays'] = df['replays']

    # ADD TO CART #
    with closing(db.connect('/Users/meter/code/mm/vid_score/test.db')) as con:
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM add_to_cart;", con)

    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.date
    df = df.drop('index', axis=1)
    df = df.loc[df['time'] == ONE]

    df = df.groupby('video_id').agg({"ios_id": {"add_to_cart": np.count_nonzero,
                                                "unique_clicks": pd.Series.nunique},
                                     "feed_position": {"feed_position": np.average}})
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)

    video_base['add_to_cart'] = df['add_to_cart']

    # CAROUSEL #
    with closing(db.connect('/Users/meter/code/mm/vid_score/test.db')) as con:
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM carousel;", con)

    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.date
    df = df.drop('index', axis=1)
    df = df.loc[df['time'] == ONE]

    df = df.groupby('video_id').agg({"ios_id": {"carousel": np.count_nonzero,
                                                "unique_clicks": pd.Series.nunique},
                                     "feed_position": {"feed_position": np.average}})
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)

    video_base['carousel'] = df['carousel']

    return video_base


def cleanup(video_raw):
    video_raw = video_raw.sort('count_watched', ascending=False)

    video_raw['percent_yesterday'] = (video_raw['count_watched'] - video_raw['count_watched_yeterday']) / video_raw[
        'count_watched_yeterday']
    video_raw['percent_seven'] = (video_raw['count_watched'] - video_raw['count_watched_seven']) / video_raw[
        'count_watched_seven']

    new_cols = ['count_watched', 'percent_yesterday', 'percent_seven',
                'unique_watched', 'avg_time_watched', 'feed_position',
                'replays', 'item_info_clicks', 'faves', 'add_to_cart', 'carousel']

    video_clean = video_raw[new_cols]

    video_clean = video_clean.rename(columns={'count_watched': 'Video Plays',
                                              'percent_yesterday': '% Change from Yest.',
                                              'percent_seven': '% Change from Last Week',
                                              'unique_watched': 'Unique Watchers',
                                              'avg_time_watched': 'Avg. Time Watched',
                                              'feed_position': 'Avg. Feed Position',
                                              'replays': 'Replays',
                                              'item_info_clicks': 'Item Info Click',
                                              'faves': 'Faved',
                                              'add_to_cart': 'Add To Cart',
                                              'carousel': 'Carousel'})

    return video_clean


def feed_position():
    with closing(db.connect('/Users/meter/code/mm/vid_score/test.db')) as con:
        df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM video_played;", con)

    print df

    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.date

    df = df.drop('index', axis=1)

    df = df.loc[df['time'] == ONE]

    df = df[['ios_id', 'video_id', 'feed_position']]

    feed_data = df.pivot_table(index=['video_id'],
                               columns=['feed_position'],
                               values=['ios_id'],
                               aggfunc=np.count_nonzero)

    feed_data.columns = feed_data.columns.droplevel(0)

    return feed_data


def to_excel(video_report, feed):
    # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('daily_report.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

    # Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
    video_report.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Video Overview', na_rep="-")

    # Get the xlsxwriter objects from the dataframe writer object.
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Video Overview']

    # Add some cell formats.
    integer = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0', 'align': 'center'})
    decimal = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00', 'align': 'center'})
    percentage = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.0%', 'align': 'center'})

    zebra = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

    worksheet.set_column('B:B', 13, integer)
    worksheet.set_column('C:C', 17, percentage)
    worksheet.set_column('D:D', 19, percentage)
    worksheet.set_column('E:E', 15, integer)
    worksheet.set_column('F:F', 15, percentage)
    worksheet.set_column('G:G', 15, decimal)
    worksheet.set_column('H:H', 13, integer)
    worksheet.set_column('I:I', 13, integer)
    worksheet.set_column('J:J', 13, integer)
    worksheet.set_column('K:K', 13, integer)
    worksheet.set_column('L:L', 13, integer)

    worksheet.set_row(3, 20, zebra)

    feed.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Feed Position', na_rep="-")

    workbook1 = writer.book
    worksheet1 = writer.sheets['Feed Position']

    integer = workbook1.add_format({'num_format': '0', 'align': 'center'})

    worksheet1.set_column('B:HU', 4, integer)

    writer.save()

def main():
    video_data = video_base()
    intent_added = video_intent(video_data)
    cleaned = cleanup(intent_added)
    feed_data = feed_position()
    to_excel(cleaned, feed_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: @ferada  This is a continuation of the last cleanup you helped me with.  Any chance you have thoughts on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the good thing is it's PEP8 clean (except for the 80 characters limit) and is readable.  `pandas` and `numpy` is very nice as well, the `groupby`
statements look great for example.  But yeah, as you said, you have a lot of duplicated code.

I've uploaded [the repo to Github](https://github.com/Ferada/video), so
you might want to clone that soonish.

### Command line arguments

It looks like you can run this just as a filter, i.e. something like
`python video.py test.db daily_report.xlsx`.  If you want more
convenience I'd suggest
[`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) to have a
nicer interface.  After that you could also add a configuration file to
store those settings locally on each machine.  However for this post
I'll restrict myself to the first option.

I don't see why you need to open/close the database so many times.  I'd
move `con` to `main` and reuse it as long as you need.  That also
eliminates all but one occurrence of that filename.  The Excel filename
can be moved to `main` as well.

Afterwards both filenames should come from the command-line instead,
i.e. `sys.argv`, of course raising an error if you don't get enough
arguments (or you know, use `argparse` to do that for you).  That now
looks like this:

```
def main():
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        sys.exit("Need exactly two arguments: database and output file.")

    with closing(db.connect(sys.argv[1])) as con:
        video_data = video_base(con)
        intent_added = video_intent(con, video_data)
        feed_data = feed_position(con)

    cleaned = cleanup(intent_added)
    to_excel(cleaned, feed_data, sys.argv[2])
```

The `cleanup` call is moved out of the `closing` body since it doesn't
depend on the order, so it makes sense to still close the database as
early as possible.

### Further refactoring

There's a typo where you used `yeterday` all the time.

Now that that's done, let's eliminate more duplication.

The first thing I see is the dups in `video_base`; basically all you
need to do here is factor out the two changing parameters:

```
def video_aggregations(df, day):
    df = df.loc[df['time'] == day]
    df = df.groupby('video_id').agg({"ios_id": {"count_watched": np.count_nonzero,
                                                "unique_watched": pd.Series.nunique},
                                     "feed_position": {"feed_position": np.average},
                                     "time_watched": {"time_watched": np.sum},
                                     "video_length": {"video_length": np.sum}})
    df.columns = df_one.columns.droplevel(0)
    return df
```

Called like:

```
df_one = video_aggregations(df, ONE)
df_one['avg_time_watched'] = df_one['time_watched'] / df_one['video_length']
```

Same thing for `video_intent` really.  Factor out the constant parts,
then call that five times.  The only thing I'm not sure about here is
the layout of the resulting data frames, so I'm more cautious than is
probably necessary - you might be able to remove the `aggregation_name`
parameter if the name isn't important:

```
def video_intent_aggregations(con, video_base, table, result_key, aggregation_name):
    df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM %s;" % table, con)

    df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s').dt.date
    df = df.drop('index', axis=1)
    df = df.loc[df['time'] == ONE]

    df = df.groupby('video_id').agg({"ios_id": {aggregation_name: np.count_nonzero,
                                                "unique_clicks": pd.Series.nunique},
                                     "feed_position": {"feed_position": np.average}})
    df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)

    video_base[result_key] = df[aggregation_name]


def video_intent(con, video_base):
    video_intent_aggregations(con, video_base, "item_info_click", "item_info_clicks", "count_clicks")
    video_intent_aggregations(con, video_base, "faved", "faves", "count_faves")
    video_intent_aggregations(con, video_base, "table", "replays", "replays")
    video_intent_aggregations(con, video_base, "add_to_cart", "add_to_cart", "add_to_cart")
    video_intent_aggregations(con, video_base, "carousel", "carousel", "carousel")
    return video_base
```

In `cleanup` you can get the values from `video_raw` once, then reuse
them:

```
watched = video_raw['count_watched']
yesterday = video_raw['count_watched_yesterday']
seven = video_raw['count_watched_seven']

video_raw['percent_yesterday'] = (watched - yesterday) / yesterday
video_raw['percent_seven'] = (watched - seven) / seven
```

And finally in `to_excel` you could extract the columns into a separate
list, then call the method on each of them:

```
columns = [('B:B', 13, integer)
           ('C:C', 17, percentage)
           ('D:D', 19, percentage)
           ('E:E', 15, integer)
           ('F:F', 15, percentage)
           ('G:G', 15, decimal)
           ('H:H', 13, integer)
           ('I:I', 13, integer)
           ('J:J', 13, integer)
           ('K:K', 13, integer)
           ('L:L', 13, integer)]

for column in columns:
    worksheet.set_column(*column)
```

Assuming I made no mistake here I'd be content with this state.  There
are still opportunities to remove duplicate code, or factor out common
code, or use more functional shortcuts, but it really it is up to you if you want to do more in that respect.  At the moment this is readable and maintainable enough IMO.